# How to configure Google Groups to reply to author only

Tags: google-groups

We have a Google group to which all members of the domain can post. However, many folks Reply-All so that their post goes to the author and the group.

Is there any setting that prevents members from posting replies to the whole group, but still lets them reply to the author?

Comment: FYI: When you reply the email gets sent to the group, therefore all members receive it. Reply-all doesn't apply since there's only one sender, the group.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: go to "Email Options" under "Settings" on the "Settings" page.

Or simply use the URL `https://groups.google.com/forum/#!groupsettings/[GROUP_NAME]/email`.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Note that this feature doesn't work as advertised: It only sets the Reply-To header of a message and doesn't prevent someone from replying to the entire group.